# Как сохранить SecretKey

Tags: java, android

Я генерирую случайный ключ шифрования таким способом

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
kgen.init(128);
final SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
```

пытаюсь сохранить его при помощи `SharedPreferences` но переменная `key` не строка и не массив байтов, как можно его сохранить?

Comment: сохранять секретный ключ в `SharedPreferences` это конечно же жесть :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете конвертировать в массив `byte[]`.

---

**Java 8**

SecretKey в строку:

```
// create new key
SecretKey secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
// get base64 encoded version of the key
String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded());
```

Обратно:

```
// decode the base64 encoded string
byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedKey);
// rebuild key using SecretKeySpec
SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");
```

---

**Java 7**

SecretKey в строку:

```
// CREATE NEW KEY
// GET ENCODED VERSION OF KEY (THIS CAN BE STORED IN A DB)

SecretKey secretKey;
String stringKey;

try {secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();}
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {/* LOG YOUR EXCEPTION */}

if (secretKey != null) {stringKey = Base64.encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT)}
```

Обратно:

```
// DECODE YOUR BASE64 STRING
// REBUILD KEY USING SecretKeySpec

byte[] encodedKey     = Base64.decode(stringKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, 0, encodedKey.length, "AES");
```

---

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355466/converting-secret-key-into-a-string-and-vice-versa)